# catalogue price rules and tier price discount do they work together if both applied

Tags: magento2.3

We have a catalogue price rule set up to discount most of our products but would also like to offer a further discount for customers who buy larger quantities so we have used the tier price option within the store. The only way we can get both rules to work is use the fixed price rule in the tier pricing if we use the discount tier price rule it doesn't work.

Should the catalogue price rule and tier price  discount rule work together of is this function not available in M2

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to set up the tier pricing rule as a percentage discount instead of a fixed price. This way, the catalog price rule and the tier pricing rule should be able to work together without any conflicts.

Comment: Hi Harun we have tried this. If a discount price rule is set the discount tier price does not seem to work. Our web designer is telling me that this will need programming but I cant understand if the option is there why it does not work but will work if I set the tier price to fixed?

Comment: If that doesn't  work Another option is to create a custom module or extension that combines the functionality of the two rules. This would allow you to create a more customized discount structure that can handle complex pricing scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Harun we will give that a try. thanks for your help